# Endofunctors on the category of groups which are Galois- related to a linear map on $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, abstract-algebra

**I thank  J.C. and Arturo Magidin for interesting suggestions in the comments to this question**

In this  post the field of rational numbers  is  denoted by $\mathbb{Q}$. The space  of  polynomials with rational coefficients is  denoted by $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. The commutator  subgroup of a  group $G$ is  denoted  by $G'$. The isomorphism between two groups is  denoted by $\simeq$

We learn from the answer to the following question

> [Is there a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $T$ on $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that for all polynomials $\mathrm{Gal}(T(f))$ is the commutator subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(f)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219076)

that **there does not exist a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $T$ on $\mathbb{Q}[x]$  such that  for all** $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ **we have** $$Gal(T(f))\simeq(Gal(f))'$$

Motivated by the above fact we ask the following question:

> Assume that $T$ is  a  a linear map over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$,     and  $\mathcal{F}$ is an endofunctor on the category of groups. we say that $T$ is  Galois-related to $\mathcal{F}$ if we have $$Gal(T(f))\simeq\mathcal{F}(Gal(f))\;\;\;\text{For  all polynomial  } f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$$

What, if any, are some  non trivial examples of such situation? (A  non identity  functor?Some interesting examples?)

Comment: @j.c.  $\mathcal{F}$ is  a  functor  on category of groups, for example, in the linked question I considered $\mathcal{F}= commutator$ and  according to the answer to that question I realized that this functor is  Galoois related to  no linear map $T$.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused! It might help to include a little more background from the other question to keep this one self-contained.  Also it may help to use the term "endofunctor".

Comment: @DimaSustretov  $T$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear on vector space $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Please see the linked question.

Comment: @j.c. You are welcome. Thank you for your suggestions. based on your comment, I revised the question.

Comment: I think the title is misleading. You are *not* seeking a "functorial approach to Galois theory". You are asking a question about functors and Galois theory, but you are not trying to approach Galois theory functorially.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  Thank you. I revise the title.

Comment: I don't see any reason to expect that such things exist, or any use to which they might be put if they did. The operation sending a polynomial to its Galois group is very sensitive and I don't expect it to have basically any good behavior.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks  for your comment.  However for a particular functor "commutator" the answer to this question is negative, see this post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219076/is-there-a-mathbbq-linear-map-t-over-mathbbqx-such-that-for-all-po?lq=1, but this negative answer contains very interesting idea. So, what about if we consider some other functors?